# Extension of divisor in family

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X \rightarrow S$ be a smooth and proper morphism of smooth complex varieties, where $S$ is a curve with a point $0\in S$.

Suppose we have a divisor $Y_0 \subset X_0$, which can be assumed to be very ample if needed.

Is there a divisor $Y \subset X$, flat over $S$, such that $Y \cap X_0 = Y_0$?

Comment: In general, the answer is no. I suggest for a counter example, you read about Lefschetz theorem. It says that a very general hypersurface of degree at least 4 in projective three space has Picard group integers, generated by hyperplanes, but special ones (for example a Fermat), has larger Picard group.